# Flow issue, Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

The following lines of code informs turtle's (shoplifters) decision whether 1) their perception of risk is low enough to attempt to shoplift and 2) whether they are caught shoplifting.

If the perception-of-risk is 60 or below and they have not previously been deterred from shoplifting, they attempt to shoplift.

- 98% of attempts are successful.
- Of the unsuccessful 2% of attempts, 5% of them are prevented. The shoplift is unsuccessful and there are no repercussions.
- Of the 95% which weren't prevented, 99% of these shoplifters are apprehended by security.
- 1% of shoplifters who were apprehended by security escape thus successfully shoplift.

Apprehension has two effects. For the caught shoplifter, apprehension deters 97% of non-professional shoplifters to not shoplift again. For up to 5 potential shoplifters who are intending to target the same store, their perception-of-risk of shoplifting at that store increases by 5.

My question is this: The line of explanation/code with the asterisks' next to them, would this work? I am trying to increase the perception-of-risk of turtles who share the same target-store as the turtle who was apprehended.

```
to number-shoplifts 
ask shoplifters [ if [pcolor] of patch-here = lime  and                       
perception-of-risk <= 60 and forever-deterred = 0          

[ifelse (random-float 1 < 0.98)  [                            
  set successful-shoplifts successful-shoplifts + 1 ]          

  [ifelse (random-float 1 < 0.05) [                            
    set successful-shoplifts successful-shoplifts + 0 ]        

    [ifelse (random-float 1 < 0.99 ) [                         
      set security-apprehension security-apprehension + 1
      if professional = 0 and (random-float 1 < 0.97) [set forever-deterred 1]   
***      ask n-of 5 shoplifters [if target-store = patch-here [ set perception-of-risk perception-of-risk + 5 ]]
      ]
      [set successful-shoplifts successful-shoplifts + 1 ]       

  ]]]]
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to test whether something like this works is to add some visible changes. Replace the indicated line with:

```
ask n-of 5 shoplifters
[ write target-store write " with risk " print perception-of-risk
  if target-store = patch-here
  [ set perception-of-risk perception-of-risk + 5
    set color red
    show perception-of-risk ]
]
```

The idea is to have some output that tells you what is going on.